# Solving integral equation on different intervals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have an integral equation where
$$f(x) + g(x) = \int_0^xf(x')dx'$$
and I know that $g(x) = f(x)$ when $x > x_0$ for some $x_0>0$. Does it make any sense to then write,
$$2f(x) = \int_0^xf(x')dx',$$
and try to find a solution for $x>x_0$?

Comment: In the particular case I posted I could almost have guessed, since the integral would still be going from $0$, thus including information about $f$ at earlier times. Is this the reason it does not make sense? Would it make any difference if the integral was replaced by, say, $f'(x)$?

Comment: I'm not sure about that because it won't be true for $x' \leq x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $g(x)$ is differentiable, then you can very easily obtain the solutions by differentiating both sides. If $g(x)$ is not differentiable, then it is not simple to solve analytically.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the equation for $x > x_0$ as

$$ 2f(x) = c + \int_{x_0}^x f(t)\ dt $$

where $c = \int_0^{x_0}f(t)\ dt$ is some constant

Then differentiate to obtain an IVP
$$ f'(x)= \frac{1}{2}f(x), \quad f(x_0) = c $$

to which the solution is
$$ f(x) = ce^{(x-x_0)/2} $$

If you assume $f(x)$ is continuous throughout, you can extend this solution to $\forall x$, and obtain a piece-wise solution for $g(x)$

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} -f(x) + \int_0^x \ f(t)\ dt, & x \le x_0 \\ f(x), & x > x_0 \end{cases} $$

I'm not entirely sure this works, so anyone can feel free to correct me.